# "Incompatible color definition" warning in xcolor package using IEEEtrans template

Tags: color, ieeetran, incompatibility, ieeeaccess

I am writing an article for IEEE Access using the `IEEEtrans.cls` and  `ieeeaccess.cls` templates.

My problem is, that these templates are using the `color` package to define the headers and I receive a list of warnings when I try to use a package using the `xcolor` package.

I can demonstrate the problem with the small modification of the IEEE Access template in Overleaf including the `changes` package in the preamble.

I added only this line to the main text of the template:

```
\usepackage[markup=underlined,commentmarkup=footnote]{changes}
```

I would like to get rid of the warnings without giving up to use the `changes` package or any other `xcolor` based packages.

I would appreciate your answers on the topic.

Please feel free to adjust the project to provide a working solution.

The Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

%If not commented, warnings given for the incompatible color definition
\usepackage[markup=underlined,commentmarkup=footnote]{changes}

\begin{document}

\section{Header}
Some text here. The colors are fine with or without the "changes" package, but warnings are listed.
\subsection{SubSection}
And also here
\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}
{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.\label{fig1}}

\EOD
\end{document}
```

Required files for the template to work can be retrieved from:
https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/access.zip

Working, editable, and shared Overleaf project:
https://www.overleaf.com/9292567342drnymnpxzbst

Comment: Hi Hadain, welcome to TeX.SE! The link you shared to Overleaf is only accessible to you, can you maybe paste your code here as a MWE?

Comment: don't link to some external project - the link will be dead soon. Add a small, complete example here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick comments. My problem with the MWE is, that my problem is related directly to a template, in a .cls How should I include something with files involved?

Comment: Furthermore, ```the ieeeaccess.cls``` template might be available for a while, thus I can link it, and my added code is already in the question...

Comment: I updated the question and included an MWE

Comment: you can not get rid of the warning, but it should be harmless, xcolor simply detects colors defined with the color syntax. But the class also use the spotcolor package, if you don't want to break the spot color you shouldn't load tikz or pgf.

Comment: hmmm, this is harmless, yes, but still annoying. Could not be a color redefinition solve the warnings? I tracked a similar issue regarding tikz, but then when I tried manually define the problematic color, I got a wrong definition of them, such as: color red defined instead of blue by that line `\definecolor{accessblue}{cmyk}{.24,1,1,0}`