# Suppress xcolor warning in ieee template with silence package

Tags: color, ieeeaccess, silence

I was using `todonotes` package with `ieeeaccess.cls`, and kept getting weird errors. So, I followed [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475304/229685) to fix this issue.

This answer works fine, but it leaves some warnings like this:

```
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 163.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 170.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 178.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 181.‬
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 1.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 208.
```

I tried to use `silence` to suppress this warning, and it failed:

```
\WarningFilter{xcolor}{Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line}
```

My `.tex` is like:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

% packages
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{support-caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{silence}

\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE} {PANTONE3015C} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 3015\SpotSpace C} {1 0.3 0 0.2}
\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}%
\graphicspath{{./img/}}

\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{foo}

\author{
\uppercase{foo}\authorrefmark{1}
}

\address[1]{foo}

\tfootnote{foo}

\markboth
{foo}
{foo}

\corresp{foo}

\begin{abstract}
foo
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
foo
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. 

\EOD
\end{document}
```

Is it because I've never included `xcolor` in my own `.tex`? How to suppress these warnings?

Comment: you shouldn't silence warnings that you don't understand. Warnings typically mean that something is wrong. Reduce your example and then contact the authors of the class/the journal publisher and ask them if the warning is a problem and what to do about it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did some research, the answer said it was "harmless". https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553204/incompatible-color-definition-warning-in-xcolor-package-using-ieeetrans-templa

Comment: there is no answer, only a comment. And it also says that if you are using spotcolors (which you do above) you shouldn't use tikz (which you do e.g. with todonotes). Remove the todonotes package and the warnings will probably disappear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your explanation. Does this mean like I cannot get rid of it without removing todonotes?

Comment: no idea, I never use the silence package. I either accept the warnings and ignore them or solve the root cause. In this case I think, if you want to produce something with spotcolors you should better avoid packages with tikz directly.

Comment: Maybe similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599917/38080 ?