# ieeeaccess: "Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition" when TikZ package is used

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, incompatibility, ieeeaccess

I am trying to prepare a paper for IEEE Open Access that uses `\documentclass{ieeeccess}` ; its template (https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/LaTeX.zip).

When I add use `tikz` package, I am having many `Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition` warning messages. Is it possible to suppress this warning message?

simplified code example:

```tex
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}  
\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE} {PANTONE3015C} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 3015\SpotSpace C} {1 0.3 0 0.2}
\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}%
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}
\author{\uppercase{First A. Author}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE},
\uppercase{Second B. Author\authorrefmark{2}, and Third C. Author,
Jr}.\authorrefmark{3},
\IEEEmembership{Member, IEEE}}

\begin{abstract}
These instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
keywords
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. If you are
reading a paper or PDF version of this document, please download the

\EOD
\end{document}
```

warning messages:

```
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 19.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/phv/n/n' undefined
`enter code here`(Font)              using `T1/phv/m/n' instead on input line 19.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 23.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 29.
```

Related: ["Incompatible color definition" warning in xcolor package using IEEEtrans template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553204/incompatible-color-definition-warning-in-xcolor-package-using-ieeetrans-templa)

Comment: Interestingly, I get a `Missing number, treated as zero` *error* in `pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex` which would be a much bigger problem.

Comment: As I commented in the related question: "But the class also use the spotcolor package, if you don't want to break the spot color you shouldn't load tikz or pgf.".

Comment: I used IEEE Access template once for my own purpose (containing Ti*k*Z), so I modify the template by replacing the use of `spotcolor` with normal `xcolor` definition.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Is there any way to fix this errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tikz package causing error in IEEE access template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440422/tikz-package-causing-error-in-ieee-access-template) The `xcolor` warnings are discussed, but it also covers the `Missing number, treated as zero` error which this code gives that would be more urgent to fix.

Answer (score 3):

I have identified a straightforward solution for this problem. Navigate to `\documentclass{ieeeccess}` and substitute `\Requirepackage{color}` with `\Requirepackage{xcolor}`. That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a  fairly simple solution.

1. Open `ieeeaccess.cls`
2. Find every instance of `\def\year`
3. Replace with `\def\Year`
4. Save and rename the `.cls` file to avoid confusion with the original `ieeeaccess.cls` (see samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's comment below)

and done.

source: https://9to5science.com/tikz-package-causing-error-in-ieee-access-template

EDIT: compiling your code gives:
[image]

Comment: I can already able to use tikz with `ieeeaccess.cls`  , already have `PANTONE ` lines in the question

Comment: From what I see, your example works  with no errors nor warnings using `pdflatex`. So what is the problem now?

Comment: @anis If you suggest to edit a class or package, please also **always** suggest to rename it. Getting help for future problems will be a nightmare if the user uses a modified without any indication of doing so in the log file and it also risks that different files with the same name will float around the internet. That's even more important for a class which is not included in the usual tex distributions. (depending on the license, renaming might even be a requirement)

Comment: Excellent point. i made an edit to clarify that point. Thank you.